# Make a rectangle from a collection of (sliced) squares

Tags: code-golf, math, integer, matrix

Inspired by [Make a Rectangle from a Triangle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/203135/78410).

### Task

There is a famous formula on the sum of first \$n\$ squares:

$$
1^2 + 2^2 + \dots + n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
$$

It is known that this number is composite for any \$n \ge 3\$.

Now, imagine a collection of row tiles (a tile of shape \$1 \times k\$ with the number \$k\$ written on each cell), and you have 1 copy of size-1 tile, 2 copies of size-2 tiles, ... and \$n\$ copies of size-\$n\$ tiles.

```
[1]  [2 2]  [2 2]  [3 3 3]  [3 3 3]  [3 3 3] ...
```

Then arrange them into a rectangle whose width and height are both \$ \ge 2\$. You can place each tile horizontally or vertically.

```
+-----+---+-+-+
|3 3 3|2 2|1|2|
+-----+---+-+ |
|3 3 3|3 3 3|2|
+-----+-----+-+
```

Output such a matrix if it exists. You don't need to indicate the boundaries; just output the resulting matrix of integers. Your program may do whatever you want if the solution doesn't exist.

I believe there exists a solution for any \$n \ge 3\$. Please let me know if you find a proof or counterexample!

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Examples

```
n = 3: (2x7 example)
3 3 3 3 3 3 1
3 3 3 2 2 2 2

n = 4: (3x10 example)
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 2 2
4 4 4 4 3 3 3 2 2 1
4 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 3 3

n = 5: (5x11 example)
5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 3 3 3
5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 3 3 1
5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 3 3 2
5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 3 3 2
5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 2 2

n = 6: (7x13 example)
6 6 6 6 6 5 5 5 5 5 3 3 3
6 6 6 6 6 5 5 5 5 3 3 3 1
6 6 6 6 6 5 5 5 5 4 3 3 3
6 6 6 6 6 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 2
6 6 6 6 6 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 2
6 6 6 6 6 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 2
6 6 6 6 6 6 4 4 4 4 4 4 2
```

Comment: related but different: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/143216/15599

Comment: Seems like \$n=10\$ is either very hard or has no solution.

Comment: [A solution for n=10](https://ideone.com/1lTlt1) @Arnauld I'm working on an explicit construction, but not completed yet.

Comment: @newbie Nice. Well, my algorithm either finds a solution almost instantly or after a looooooong time for some values (10, 33, 34, 41...). ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: The title is wrong: you are making a rectangle from rectangles, not squares

Comment: @isaacg Do you have any better title?

Comment: @Bubbler "Make a thick rectangle from a collection of thin rectangles"

Comment: @Bubbler or just "Make a rectangle from a collection of tiles"?

Comment: It sure seems like there ought to be some nice geometrical reason this always works, similar to the proofs for sum of squares and cubes themselves.  Have you posted on math stackexchange?

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>238 ...</s> 186 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to @Arnauld!*

*-5 bytes thanks to @ovs!!*

*-6 bytes thanks to @Jonathan Allan!!*

```python
n=input()
p=w=~n*n*(~n-n)/6
e=range(n+1)
def f(a,b,c,d=[]):1>a>exit(c);1>b>f(a-1,w,c+[d]);g=n;exec"e[g]-=1;g<=b>-1<e[g]>f(a,b-g,c,d+[g]*g);e[g]+=1;g-=1;"*n
while 1:1>p%w>f(p/w,w,[]);w-=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY3LCoMwEEX3foUIhTyRdNFC4@RHxIXGGIUyDcUSu/HX06TLO3PuueG7ry@8poSwYfjshFYBIpzIkJETJdL2Vjl4j@gdQa5oNbulXsgoJmHFDP1AH8qMxh3bTizVykwmf6USUVjezwPVHlC7w9nG9X6QoLTvYDJSdSWbv0r6IuM5M091ufPCFbhhWMV1e7pa5aFwibkR2pj1eVrHjKR0/wE)

Notice that the above code only used horizontal tiles. To prove it's correct...

---

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 4355 bytes

This code is an explicit construction using only horizontal tiles for \$n>6\$. It can produce correct solutions (at least) up to \$n=99\$.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void dim(int x,int&p,int&q)
{
	int u[]={x,x+1,x+x+1},o=0;
	while(u[o]%2) ++o; u[o]/=2;
	o=0; while(u[o]%3) ++o; u[o]/=3;
	sort(u,u+3);if(x%3==1)swap(u[0],u[1]);
	p=u[0];q=u[1]*u[2];
}
int o[100][99999],c[99999],g[99999];
void brute(int n,int& v,int& u,bool t)
{
	for(int i=1;i<=n;++i) c[i]=i;
	if(t)
	{
		u=n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)/6,v=2;
		while(u%v) ++v;
		if(n>=5) v=u/v;
		u/=v; c[2]-=n==6;
	}
	for(int i=1;i<=v;++i)
	{
		int s=u,cnt=0;
		for(int j=n;j>=1;--j) while(s>=j&&c[j])
		{
			s-=j, --c[j]; for(int k=j;k--;) o[i][++cnt]=j;
		}
	}
	c[2]+=t&&n==6;
	for(int i=u;i>=u-1&&i;--i)
		for(int j=1;j<=v;++j) if(!o[j][i])
		{
			int x=0; while(!c[x]) ++x;
			--c[x]; int l=x; --j;
			while(l--) o[++j][i]=x;
		}
}
int s0[99999],s1[99999];
//find a subset of a with sum b
//guaranteed b is half of a's sum
//guaranteed a is consecutive
pair<vector<int>,vector<int>> solve2(vector<int> a,int b)
{
	if(!a.size()) return make_pair(a,a);
	int w=0,s=0,as=a.size();
	for(int i=0;i<as;++i)
		s0[i+1]=s0[i]+a[i],
		s1[i+1]=s1[i]+a[as-1-i];
	while(w<a.size()&&s+a[w]<=b)
		s+=a[w++];
	assert(w!=a.size()&&w>0);
	for(int l=0;l<w;++l)
	{
		int r=w-1-l;
		int p=s0[l]+s1[r];
		if(p>b) continue;
		int q=b-p;
		if(!(a[l]<=q&&q<=a[as-r-1]))
			continue;
		//first l, last r, q.
		vector<int> A,B;
		for(int j=0;j<l;++j) A.push_back(a[j]);
		A.push_back(q);
		for(int j=as-r;j<as;++j) A.push_back(a[j]);
		for(int j=l;j<as-r;++j)
		{
			if(a[j]==q) q=-1;
			else B.push_back(a[j]);
		}
		return make_pair(A,B);
	}
	assert(0);
}
int main()
{
	int n,p,q;
	cin>>n;
	assert(n>=3);
	if(n<=6) brute(n,p,q,1);
	else
	{
		if(n%3==1)
		{
			int x=n%3,pp,qq;
			dim(x,p,q);
			brute(x,p,q,0);
			while(n!=x)
			{
				//x+1...x+3
				int xx=x+3; dim(xx,pp,qq);
				assert(pp-p==2&&qq-q==x*3+6);
				for(int i=x+1;i<=x+3;++i) c[i]=i;
				int mr=x/6;
				for(int i=1;i<=p;++i)
				{
					int cnt=q;
					vector<int> rv;
					if(i<=mr) rv=vector<int>{x+2,x+2,x+2};
					else rv=vector<int>{x+1,x+2,x+3};
					for(int j:rv)
					{
						assert(c[j]); --c[j];
						for(int k=j;k--;) o[i][++cnt]=j;
					}
				}
				vector<int> rv;
				for(int i=x+1;i<=x+3;++i)
					for(int j=c[i];j;--j) rv.push_back(i);
				pair<vector<int>,vector<int>> s=solve2(rv,qq);
				for(int i=p+1;i<=pp;++i)
				{
					int cnt=0;
					for(auto j:(i==pp)?s.first:s.second)
					{
						assert(c[j]); --c[j];
						for(int k=j;k--;) o[i][++cnt]=j;
					}
				}
				p=pp; q=qq; x=xx;
			}
		}
		else
		{
			int x=n%6,pp,qq;
			dim(x,p,q);
			brute(x,p,q,0);
			while(n!=x)
			{
				int xx=x+6; dim(xx,pp,qq);
				if(n%6==0)
					assert(pp-p==1&&qq-q==24*x+90); //[1 2 3 4 5 6]*3+[2 3 5 5 6 6]
				else if(n%6==2)
					assert(pp-p==2&&qq-q==12*x+39); //[1 2 3 4 5 6]+[1 1 2 3 5 6]
				else if(n%6==3)
					assert(pp-p==2&&qq-q==12*x+45); //[1 2 3 4 5 6]+[1 2 4 5 6 6]
				else if(n%6==5)
					assert(pp-p==1&&qq-q==24*x+78); //[1 2 3 4 5 6]*3+[1 1 2 2 4 5]
				else assert(0);
				vector<int> uv;
				if(n%6==0) uv=vector<int>{2,3,5,5,6,6};
				else if(n%6==2) uv=vector<int>{1,1,2,3,5,6};
				else if(n%6==3) uv=vector<int>{1,2,4,5,6,6};
				else uv=vector<int>{1,1,2,2,4,5};
				for(int j=1;j<4/(pp-p);++j)
					for(int k=1;k<=6;++k) uv.push_back(k);
				for(int i=x+1;i<=x+6;++i) c[i]=i;
				for(int i=1;i<=p;++i)
				{
					int cnt=q;
					for(auto j_:uv)
					{
						int j=j_+x;
						assert(c[j]); --c[j];
						for(int k=j;k--;) o[i][++cnt]=j;
					}
				}
				vector<int> rv;
				for(int i=x+1;i<=x+6;++i)
					for(int j=c[i];j;--j) rv.push_back(i);
				if(pp-p==2)
				{
					pair<vector<int>,vector<int>> s=solve2(rv,qq);
					for(int i=p+1;i<=pp;++i)
					{
						int cnt=0;
						for(auto j:(i==pp)?s.first:s.second)
						{
							assert(c[j]); --c[j];
							for(int k=j;k--;) o[i][++cnt]=j;
						}
					}
				}
				else
				{
					int i=pp,cnt=0;
					for(auto j:rv)
					{
						assert(c[j]); --c[j];
						for(int k=j;k--;) o[i][++cnt]=j;
					}
				}
				p=pp; q=qq; x=xx;
			}
		}
	}
	cerr<<p<<","<<q<<"\n";
	for(int i=1;i<=p;++i,cout<<"\n")
		for(int j=1;j<=q;++j)
			cout<<setw(2)<<o[i][j]<<" ";
	if(n>6)
	{
		for(int i=1;i<=n;++i) c[i]=i;
		for(int i=1;i<=p;++i)
			for(int j=1;j<=q;++j)
			{
				int u=o[i][j];
				assert(u>=1&&u<=n);
				for(int k=2;k<=u;++k)
					assert(o[i][++j]==u);
				--c[u];
			}
		for(int i=1;i<=n;++i) assert(!c[i]);
	}
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xVdtc5s4EP5s/wolN/WZIGyDY@5akG/av@FjMpiQRDYGjBBmruPfnlu9YIODm7Y3nUvGgJZ9ebTaZyWiPLeeo@j19TeaRgl/jJG/piWbsvIxMs3Jy3LIGU2fURruYpaHUYzgjTesMvqIHuluTNMS1Riuo1xe98bw63AgpHwVkK81rk0bfnA94ozMvOHg8EKTeMxXWfDBMZBpZh4Sgylx4KVQQS2NeUdjDhosK8oxx9ycGx59Gtcf5oTYBjuEOVjMAsxXdmCAXk7E0NsTIbjjKyfwhsehAJat7NksWH0UfwGOmodn/aAnty54GcvppXJiqFI3jtdZlqBSzvMpK6QKJbZHfZJ6pkkNFK1oQChgAHygNwDFASfp3Tg1beNu7NyJ@9TFlZxyk5APlZhrJSRgly7JwkAV4VMp4VNSeeDYCSySEuKC7PgmfCXDq3hCzAjHUVrKrJ90N4ByswQDy9oYOtVsSTajUbTaBGAtzQfMIhuMLEsIPdQYb8nG21qWZ0ASabAyTXAfgAwsjhKRQGiScjTSIM8IuUeXhFv2aEQhtIDZgmR7GwUfIMHkbzKICgFOaGSVnUvjJlrVgchWLSIPBMoaUAqthNQewJaQdGYTyxJ4wbnwSWqFVtUCmzXLz@zT@k@nTzR9RCFifM1iKJgneD7Q8gUEO7SG9888LMK0jGOoE0QZegmTJ6n2OxM6XY1QaERZyuKIl7SKh3lIC7@KozIrfACxxK3nJWJZUsXOuCVDoSg9tFbUgvSEE0b/iceGgYq45EWKduE2fhBuxyEORfUL/QOZYQa/kJHGoLMiM6iZkOmaGUAmqGkHRNwDM4QLFlJbS20lDZllWzQ40fjgN65HIwbvD4FP1tKdSWBkmkI1ZCwG0h5uyFn5sJy10SSAJvEPACZpFXBBDhAu8fQwF@CSwAQwRaB5ki/XhkhuSVMeN4p7srZyrXAzDsHGJ/vRaO8TOYPCghYhQA7ahmLVCwZQMEpCuBcY7Scgby/EZ/yly6UZFG6i6vbzJOfs5WEdRlsIuZFNaNAW7o2urUAC5nIJrtmftROpChZC@cSLJ6lKyN6ASVu2rPo4YTH60ucNCDp4UzEwJ0O1E71OYmEUO3YhTcenhp7iHO9BM6Lpcpme1xVa1dxQ3S71iWvo1inVsS3eCER6VUFHdewutUGIc9DfyxmIjaUW5hL1QPmTAjwzWsxOb0gt11F6ghWEbWYymdTmXI6l65rA0JN7VV2rGMpFAx82wJwQB8pjb@0Jqe/mpqs1zlwBx6LDClfdFq/D7ApST91LK2mTNwxrYEoD0ZfVZLsVVlRaCJkC410BHK9IS@NrbTpY/45aV674GzVbq80btVMxfSoqBahB1ORCbgFe0/b1u@9o/gNVW821b0JXc3mBjYjUehu1PRVVq4ypXpV32ifRDbSozkt9Dp6r4Pn1VZm1shXyMoN0jSkBC@MvNpEt4hObQC/P0sdfmsRcgARWAyeAILXa6o6axYpRXQa5/51BJ8a4vYyR7HUJmemJdxhkNwxy7u9q8yOEQdPpykYOmqN7tEBuAMxaidFCjGA8PNVu49jpc3yipu2A4/nHt45NGKnxotft/H2394t@t4567nW7eD8Nf/zZnwaFVzpvOW414Esa8epyCUDUIbyD53gB/y52NeEvUntpYGMbK6Neg3mPgYPv30bodSs1j132qXPe/VRmymg2sg45bG8LWwi82oroLfJvr7dk921L/uEWfCb7wyd@2RwV9s2DPm7@X@3S/bl2KQ5JquA7GfiJLvrtNtpJV7uR/kAnPfn4Zoa/M8U6u51U677ZqQOYTY6vdP5fvFF@q8eLr6m4KHw/9/1bfOv7e7j/nd56w97yxlHGS6XR8221P7FNqcFnzWHsGL4vEW4CMES3@gy3dPUR/J2v2@ssuxr8vMtwoiN3zmJ8Kfonh1gXdN/CpzJ0Bi47Q6fr6hSLQzDXRmJVeHDKZf80tPmNmI46/x5fX@3Zvw)

---

## How does the construction work?

It's an incremental construction. Consider \$n \bmod 6\$, we can have these values for height and width of rectangles:

- \$n/6\times (n+1)(2n+1)~(n\bmod 6=0)\$
- \$(2n+1)/3\times n(n+1)/2~(n\bmod 6=1)\$
- \$(n+1)/3\times n(2n+1)/2~(n\bmod 6=2)\$
- \$n/3\times (n+1)(2n+1)/2~(n\bmod 6=3)\$
- \$(2n+1)/3\times (n+1)n/2~(n\bmod 6=4)\$
- \$(n+1)/6\times n(2n+1)~(n\bmod 6=5)\$

(dimensions might be \$1\$ for \$n\leq 6\$ so these small cases are handled manually)

So the main idea of my construction is:

- We construct rectangles with the heights and widths as in above list.
- If \$n\bmod 3 \neq 1\$, construct the solution for \$n-6\$ recursively, add in \$n-5,n-4\cdots n\$. The height of the rectangle will only increase 1 or 2.
- If \$n\bmod 3=1\$, construct the solution for \$n-3\$ recursively and add in \$n-2,n-1,n\$. The height of the rectangle will only increase 2.
- We first carefully assign the new numbers to the added columns, and then put rest of the numbers into one or two added rows.

The rest of the job is some careful casework to pick the numbers. These details are left as an exercise to the readers (Be ready for some long and tedious casework!). If you complete all the details, this should become a formal proof for the existence of the solutions (and using only horizontal tiles!).

Comment: you can save 2 bytes with `p=~n*n*(~n-n)/6`

Comment: You can get rid of the `if` statements in `f`: `1>a>exit(c);1>b>f(a-1,bb,c+[d],bb);g=n`.

Comment: I see what you mean, thanks! @ovs

Comment: A somewhat complicated 1 byte save removing the multi-line while [here](https://tio.run/##JY2xDoMgFEV3voKlCQjE4OAgwo8YBxREk@aVNDa0i79OIY7v3XPvib9zf0GXM@gD4uckFEV9QQMNuUAAbXvk9dtC8ASYpCjpDjm/4Y1YvvCVOz3NdEBYGmv89zjJSpU0iym5kDzxlU1upipoQDjtx9PjMPgpzEJLFUa9GCHHeltw96YIdZWVVxOoqhGraOHR3ZeDNPGRiiG2qRiKX6XC5Nz/AQ)

Comment: ...in fact, save 3 more removing the `and` I used [here](https://tio.run/##JY3LDoMgEEX3fAWbJiAQgwsX4vAjxoUPRJNmShob2o2/TqFd3rlnzg2fc39gkxLCgeF1Mk4CXFhhxS5UyOuWOHhO6B1DoTmJ0JDVbXRjk5zlIlcYRt4Rqu1k3fs42cKNtrPNvdIyykUM68iNByQ07sfdUd@5wY8KtPE9zFbpvmT7EypflCLnynNT7qJwGSb/Z91pG24x06GOWZ/HTcxMSu0X)

Comment: [Start wide](https://tio.run/##JY7NDsIgEITvPAUXE2ghzZrooXR5kaaH/lBsYlZiatBLXx1Bj7Mz38yGz3570Dklwo3CaxeSRQx4UEWVOEiTbK7M4XMk7wTVINniVr6KUU1qVgv2g2wZBzta9952MUsDdrLZ16Cimut@GaTxSIzH23Z33Leu94NGML7DyWroira/Qu1LZZ115aUp97rkcpj9YWhjIcGGU8xIaGLeyB@kdPkC) and save 2 more

Comment: @Arnauld No it won't, it will find [bogus results](https://tio.run/##JY1LDoMgFEXnrIIhCMRgkw7Ex0aMAz@IJs2TNDa0E7dOoR3e37nhc24HNikh7BheJ@MkwIUVVuxChby@EwfPEb1jKDQnERqyuJWubJSTnOUC/cBbQrUdrXvvJ5u50XayOVdaRjmLfhm48YCExm1/OOpb1/tBgTa@g8kq3RVtf0DlC1JkXXluii9KL5fJf6zblYU6ZnC@NTGnKd2@)

Comment: As a bonus starting wide gives results much more quickly too - 7-44 no longer time out (45 is where we hit default recursion limits).

Comment: [2 bytes shorter](https://tio.run/##HY1BDoMgEEX3nMI0aQICMbhwURwuYlwoIpo0U9LYYDdenUKXf@b998P32F7YpoSwY/gclJEAF9ZY0wslsqYjDt4TekeRK0YitGRxa7XSSczCigWGkT2UmYw794NappWZTf5KJaKwfFhGpj2gdqezNzf4UYLSvofZSNWXbP4q6YuM51x7psudF67AtxpJ3Panq1QeCveYG6GJWZ@ndcxcSt0P) and a lot slower by replacing the while loop with `exec`.

Comment: Seems starting wide and just greedily placing tiles for each row can straightly find answer for... 8-357. @JonathanAllan Thanks!

Comment: This backtrack is surprisingly fast. My c++ port can find answer for 2-3000 with lightning speed :o

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 188 bytes

A shorter version inspired by [@newbie's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203451/58563).

```javascript
f=(n,w=2)=>(g=(h,a,m,r=[])=>h%1||r[w]?1:r[w-1]?--h*g(h,a,M=[...m,r]):a.every((_,j,[...a])=>a[j]++>j++||g(h,a,m,[...r,...Array(j).fill(j)])))(n*(~n-n)*~n/6/w,Array(n).fill(0),[])?f(n,w+1):M
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU5LboMwEN3nFLOpmMHGKa2UBalBPUBOQFFlJfwsMo6cKigqzdWpSbPqZt7o/fSsuZjz3venr4TdoZ7nRiPLUb@QzrHV2Ekjj9LrsgpE95ROky/HqkizAElaFUnSxe3dtdOlUip4K8qMqi@1vyJ@SisX2ixxU9pKiNwKMU3to3kRvQzn3XtzRUuq6YchYEVEyDHeOGGKb7zerEf5Z@KH6ZlkmFU0y2CRUrabG@eRQcPrFhjeNGwCCkHwvQLYOz67oVaDazFiHYEApu0/oVnKj@aEHnQOXlnXM0YQET3eD44oJO@4@pl/AQ)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (                           // f is a recursive function taking:
  n, w = 2                      //   n = input, w = width of matrix
) => (                          //
g = (                           // g is a recursive function taking:
  h, a,                         //   h = height of matrix, a[] = array of counters
  m, r = []                     //   m[] = matrix, r[] = current row
) =>                            // (g returns 0 for success or 1 for failure)
  h % 1 ||                      // if h is not an integer or
  r[w] ?                        // the length of r[] is w + 1 (i.e. r[] is too long):
    1                           //   abort
  :                             // else:
    r[w - 1] ?                  //   if the length of r[] is w:
      --h *                     //     decrement h and force success if h = 0
      g(                        //     do a recursive call with:
        h, a,                   //       h and a[] unchanged
        M = [...m, r]           //       a new matrix M[] with r[] appended
      )                         //     end of recursive call
    :                           //   else:
      a.every((_, j, [...a]) => //     for each entry at position j in a[]:
        a[j]++ > j++ ||         //       unless a[j] is greater than j,
        g(                      //       do a recursive call with:
          h, a, m,              //         h, a[] and m[] unchanged
          [ ...r,               //         j added j times to the current row
            ...Array(j).fill(j) //         NB1: both j and a[j] where incremented above
          ]                     //         NB2: a[] is a local copy defined in this loop
        )                       //       end of recursive call
      )                         //     end of every()
)(                              // initial call to g with:
  n * (~n - n) * ~n / 6 / w,    //   h = n(n+1)(2n+1) / 6 / w
  Array(n).fill(0),             //   a[] initialized to n 0's
  []                            //   an empty matrix
) ? f(n, w + 1) : M             // return M[] on success, or try again with w + 1
```

---

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>297</s>  287 bytes

A brute-force search, which always try to put the biggest available rectangles first.

```javascript
f=(n,i=2,k=n*(~n-n)*~n/6,A=n=>n?[0,...A(n-1)]:[])=>k%i||!(g=(m,a,x,y=m.findIndex(r=>r.some(v=>!v*~++x,x=-1)))=>~y?a.some((v,j)=>[0,1].some(r=>v<(o=n-j)&o<=(r?i-y:k/i-x)&&g(M=m.map(r=>[...r]),b=[...a],b[(h=p=>p--?h(p,M[y+r*p][x+!r*p]=o):j)(o)]++))):1)(A(i).map(_=>A(k/i)),A(n))?f(n,i+1):M
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVDBboJAEL37FeuhOiMLlpp4oA6EYw@eeqSkQUVclFmyGgKp5dfpoklP72Vm3nszU2ZNdt0bVd9c1od8GI4ELBW9yTPxAnp2GRc9L9cyJqaQo@RVep4XA7s@pkGSIoXnF3W/T6EgqGQmW9lR5R0VHz74kLdgKDTeVVc5NBROm0XvOK1sycrRavsuyp5daGRpC9bfT58Vq2w2oIndEmd6Q2Ai5XbBeancFmezArY2qMrqcTCxS5kU5Y5GlqVyl8CJagpr141OUMtt0jlmUadJ60xHJI1BiaAxdRy7SeAjxKDw4fdNYQw2BlHaQxGj4/gTx8dgOxy1ARYkVu@CxUb4rxatg/iZCLHXfNWX3LvoAqzkaWYEhcI8KI@UvZv@vBnFBazWiF6pFcN8/s@@eI7CEQ@c/A5/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 148 bytes

finds random matrix with only horizontal tiles.
It is very slow for n>5 but this is code-golf...

```
(While@!MatrixQ[Join@@@(w=TakeList[d=RandomSample@Flatten[Table[#~Table~#,#]&/@Range@#,1],r=RandomChoice@IntegerPartitions[#(#+1)/2][[2;;-2]]])];w)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7NCoJAFEZfpRgQJUMUWokwEARFgf1Ai2EWN72Ml3SM8YKtfPVJqtXZnPPxdcANdsBUgTeFD@8NtSiXJ2BH77M69GSllOFY3OCJRxpY1cUFbN13V@hes7prgRmtusGjRSWmLycRCx0kcjYNShGnOnb/bNv0VKHcW0aDrgTHxNTbQYlQrNIoybRSWZ6vM611pPMxCnzpyHIiw98ZMe8ujNroyPsP)

here is also a very quick random generator for test cases up to 6

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 97 bytes

```
(While@!MatrixQ[Join@@@(w=Partition[RandomSample@Flatten[Table[#~Table~#,#]&/@Range@#,1],3])];w)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY29CsIwFEZfRRsoLQ0UEVxq4E4dBKH@gEPIcNXQXmgSCRfq1FePpU5n@M7HcciDdcj0wtSrVDwGGi1sz8iRvhd9CuQBoJhUh5GJKXh9Rf8O7obus5jtiMzW6zs@R6vFvHIWUpi8hsXsLQi5M3JvStNMZZ7aEDWpvaSjOkiqKtlF8lxD8U@J5bbpNZmyWQfIMpPSDw)